# Action connection and autoresize problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, warnings, action, autoresize

Generally, I am making an app with two View Controllers and each of them are connected to each other. However, when I run the app, the debugger reveals the warning that: "`2014-07-30 23:07:49.382 Random[1437:60b] Action connections from <UIView: 0x10951eb90; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x10951b9c0>> are not supported.`"

The app can run as usual but I have no idea why this problem can happen. Anyone knows how to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem because I had an Outlet link to my view.

My view was an `UIControl` linked to an `IBAction` and I changed this `UIControl` to `UIView` and forget removing the `IBAction` link.

Removing the link will solved your problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a lot of time. That was it for me too, although I had to look at views in view controllers not directly related to the segue to find it! First I dumped all the subviews in the source and destination view controller, and when the UIView address in the warning message didn't show in the controllers or their views subviews, I broadened my search to other controllers and their views.

Like you, I had temporarily subclassed a UIView as a UIControl to trap tap on background, then changed it back to UIView without deleting the action in Interface Builder.

Comment: This was EXACTLY my problem too! Thought I'd spend forever tracking this down and the first place I looked was here. Kudos to you!